# WCF single threaded? Sync calls?

Tags: multithreading, wcf, thread-safety

I have a WCF service that acts as a middleware between applications: thw WCF receives several calls from several clients (say, system A). Each one of the calls results in a call to another system (say, system B).

Is it possible to make the calls to system B occur one each time? Instead of paralelyzing the calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If system B doesn't care which thread it is called on, but you just want to make sure it isn't called by multiple threads at the same time (perhaps because you know system B relies on global variables or global state), you can use a simple mutex lock to make all the threads line up and go through system B single file.  Something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
  private static object _lockObj = new Object();

  public void MyFunction()
  {
    lock(_lockObj)  
    {
      system_B_call(etc);
    }
  }
}
```

Important: All functions that you want to "throttle" must use the same lock object instance.

If your system B is sensitive to which thread it is called on (many UI frameworks including WinForms and WCF require UI changes to occur on the main UI thread), then you will need to marshal the calls onto a specific thread. There are several ways to do this, one of which is to use a [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.send.aspx) and its Post or Send methods.